# How to make an Es6 react program to count number of letters in string in input box ? I have tried above code, but am not able to show on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, ecmascript-6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le4Sw.png)In console, i am able to see the output, but on screen, it's not coming. How to input the string from user on input box, then show the results on screen? Is something wrong with the logic? Is there any better method?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const CharCount = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [print, setPrint] = useState(false)

    const count= (value)=>{
       const result = [...value].reduce((a, e) => { a[e] = a[e] ? a[e] + 1 : 1; return a }, [])
        console.log(result, typeof(result))
        return result
}
   const getData=(e)=>{
    setData(e.target.value)
    setPrint(false)
   }

  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={data} onChange={getData}/>
        <button onClick={()=>setPrint(true)}>CLICK!</button>
    {
     print ? count(data):"error"
    }
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharCount
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that is supposed to output the result to the screen

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: Don't call `setPrint(false)` from `count`.

Comment: please check image above. setprint(false) needs to be called, otherwise, result will come after every key press, rather then single button click

Comment: No, `print` is initially `false`. The result will show only once you've clicked the button for the first time - and yes, after that it will update with every onchange event. Is that not what you want? But if you *immediately* set it to `false` during the rendering, it will *never* show. If you want to hide it again, do that separately - not in the `count` function.

Comment: agreed. To verify, i just updated the code, moved the setprint to another function. still i am getting correct data on console, but not on ui.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes more sense. Now, why does React still not render anything? That's because you're [abusing an array with non-integer properties](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/). React will only see an empty array (with `.length` 0), and render nothing. Use `{}` as the initial value of your `reduce` instead. But React still won't know how to print that. Do something like `{ print ? JSON.stringify(count(data)) : null }` instead.

Comment: when i console typeOf(result) , its coming an object not an array. What is happening?

Comment: `typeof []` is `"object"`, since every array is an array object. You could find the difference with `Array.isArray(result)`

Comment: is there a different approach for doing this?